# How do I progressively slow down a timer when 'stop' function is called?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of 52 UIImages which I'm accessing with:

```
let cards: [UIImage] = Deck.allValues
```

I am attaching a timer to fire off a random element from said array every 0.1 seconds

```
   func startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(showRandomCard), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I also have other functions to stop, and restart the timer (basically just timer.invalidate() & startTimer())

I would like to know if it's possible, when stopping the timer, to make the timeInterval slow down progressively, as if you were spinning a wheel and it slows to a halt.

I apologise if I've asked this question badly, it's my first post here and I was dreading it. If this question has been answered already I do apologise.

For reference, here is the #selector I'm using for the timer:

```
@objc func showRandomCard() {
    cardImageView.image = cards.randomElement() ?? UIImage.init(named: "AS")
```

Comment: create a variable like `timerInterval: Double = 0.1` then when you're timer ends subtract some value from it and when you start the timer use `timerInterval` instead of the hardcoded `0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Does Data already said, use a variable.

Set a max and a min value in your controller and use a function or computed variable.

**Example**:

```swift
let maxInterval = 2.0
let minInterval = 0.1
var timerInterval = 0.1

func nextInterval() -> TimeInterval?{
    let next = timerInterval + 0.1
    guard next <= maxInterval else { return nil }

    return next
}

@objc func startTimer(){
    if let next = nextInterval(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: next, target: self, selector: #selector(showRandomCard), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

never be sorry to ask questions

Peace

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, you should have another event to set it back to 0.1.